# What am I doing wrong with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a complete noob in Python/programming - so apologies for this silly question

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Alarm app")
window.geometry('300x300')


def Funk():
    print('Hi you')
    Funk()     

btn = Button(window, text="show", command=Funk)
btn.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

The executed function keeps on looping with the rest of the program. I just want the function to run ONCE.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you only wanted it to run once, why does `Funk` rerun itself?

Comment: lol, missed that extra line , thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
def Funk():
    print('Hi you')
    Funk()  #This is going to return it so it repeats printing non stop "Hi you"
```

Removed the function Funk() in def Funk

```
def Funk():
    print('Hi you')
    #Function "Funk()" Removed so it can move on.
```

I might believe you are confused. If you add Funk() in your def Funk(): You will get a repeat going on. You only call that function "Funk()" When you want code in it to be used.

Comment: That's not what "return" means.